# MS Access 2013 Memos became Long Text and Queries truncates to 255

Tags: ms-access

We upgraded to MS Access 2013. I have many MDBs that were 2010 and are now 2013.
Memo fields were never a problem. Query them and get all the data.
Now, with Long Text, a query within the MDB will return only 255 characters
However, this happens in only one of several MDBs. The other MDBs I've tested with Long Text work as expected.

Any ideas? I searched high and low and many similar problems, but no fixes that work. Formatting in the database is NOT set to "@"

Answer (score 0):

If you use some type of formatting on the resulting query/memo, then it truncated to 255 chars. So remove any formatting if you using some kind of control to display the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Posts in other forums say that the truncation problem is solved if you define the field as rich text instead of long text in both the table and the report.